# TcpTimedWaitDelay is missing in Windows Server 2012

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, tcp, tcpip

Suddenly my server log shows:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

And I googled and found these links as suggestions to resolve this issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/842585/getting-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full
[Getting "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient ..." when server access the internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/661476/getting-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lack)

They say that you can change the value of `TcpTimedWaitDelay` in registry and the problem might go away. However, I can't find this value on Windows Server 2012. I simply can add it. But I can't be sure if it truly helps or not, because I truly don't have an idea of how to measure the result of this key.

What should I do? Should I add that key to the registry?

Comment: Increasing the number of dynamic TCP ports might help performance too
     `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=1025 num=64511`

See how to [Adjust the MaxUserPort and TcpTimedWaitDelay settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance)

Answer (score 2):

`TcpTimedWaitDelay` is fully supported in Windows Server 2012

You may have to set the `StrictTimeWaitSeqCheck` as well, for `TcpTimedWaitDelay` to be of effect:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"StrictTimeWaitSeqCheck"=dword:00000001`

Setting or changing these will require a reboot for the changes to be in effect.

There is no way of telling if these changes will solve your particular problem, but they are easily reversible if not.

HTH